# How to lookup disk "Device Identifier" from "Device / Media Name"?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, command-line

There are 20+ drives in the system. One of the drives is having issues according to the disk controller. The disk controller reports to me by the drives serial number. That drive serial I can map to a "Device / Media Name" (f.e. `HPT DISK 1_7 Media`).

#### Device / Media Name → Device Identifier

Next, I do wish to know the "**Device Identifier**" (like `disk8`) or "**Device Node**" (f.e. `/dev/disk8`).

---

#### Regression

Having to do a `diskutil info /dev/diskZZ` for all of the 20+ drives is quite inefficient.

---

What is the efficient way to do a command-line lookup for the disk its "Device Identifier" having the "Device / Media Name" using Lion (Mac OS X 10.7)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will output the device node for any volume with a matching name by replacing `<string>` with the Device/ Media Name you're searching for.

```
for d in /dev/disk*; do
    if [ `diskutil info $d | grep -c <string>` == 1 ]; then
        diskutil info $d | grep "Node"
    fi
done
```

#### One-liner

```
$ for disk in /dev/disk*; do [ `diskutil info $disk | grep -c '<string>'` == 1 ] && diskutil info $disk | grep Node; done
```

BTW, on my MacBook Pro I have two "drives" with the same device name as they are two volumes on an APFS drive so some people reading this may have similar happening. I also don't have a 10.7 Mac available to test it, but it doesn't rely on any fancy shell stuff so should work fine. It certainly works on 10.12 and 10.13.

Comment: This shell script loop (and the one-liner) also works as expected on 10.7.

Answer (score 0):

```
for d in /dev/disk*; do
diskinfo info $d | grep <string>
done
```

Or similar.

Comment: Actually, that won't work. The output of `diskutil info <device identifier>` is multiple lines so your script will return "Device / Media Name:      <string>" and nothing else.

Comment: :thumbup: I may have rushed it, with no testing. Also thought OP might do some shell script research :)

Comment: Yeh, looked at the output now, I see what you mean. You need to match the ID with the disk, then output the disk ID that that line appears in.